# How can I create a user under linux and a X509 'pem' file to use with them?

Tags: linux

Rather than request a public key to put into the user's authorized_keys, I would rather generate a key I can send to the user and tell them to use with their client,

ssh -i keyfile.pem host.server.com

Comment: you typically would just generate the RSA/DSA keys for the use with ssh in this manner. If *you* are generating a x.509 certificate including the private key, x.509 would not have any significant advantage over the much simpler RSA/DSA authentication.

Comment: Can you guarantee that you can send the private key and it's pass phrase to the user in a safe manner?

Answer (score 2):

You're still looking at generating a keypair (with a tool like `ssh-keygen`) and sending the user the **private** key in order to connect to your server.  Note that this creates a few security problems.  Namely you need a secure way to get the private key to them, and they lose the ability to control their private key.